# Google maps like controls for API web maps available?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there a library available that mimics the map controls seen on the customer facing maps application as shown in the screenshot? I'd like to have something similar for an application using Maps API v3 to add my custom menu entries/actions.

I know that it is not available out of the box from the API and I know that it is possible to create custom controls to add them to the map. But maybe there's already a library/script that
implements this as a custom control which I was not able to find and that could be used instead of writing it from scratch.

[image: controls]

Comment: What controls do you mean? Regular Zoom and Navigation are availabel in the API.

Comment: Added a screenshot to show which controls I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "No" - but that's too short. So I have to type a bit more so this doesn't become a comment.

You can always check the [Google Maps API 3 Utility Library](https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries) for options not included in the main API.